# What does a period do after the first parameter of an adr instruction in arm64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, instructions

There's this instruction I found in a source:

```
adr x0, .
```

And I've never seen a dot used there, it's usually an address, so what does it do?

Comment: Its refer to the address of this exact instruction.

Comment: what did you see when you disassembled it?

Comment: this is gnu assembler yes?